# Haskell- Error using Tuples and List

Tags: haskell

I'm testing this code:

```
    puntosEnCircunferencia  ::  Float -> (Float , Float) -> [(Float , Float)] -> [(Float , Float)] 
puntosEnCircunferencia a y z = filter auxPuntos z 
   where auxPuntos (w,s) (k,r) = ((k - w)^2 + (r - s)^2) < (a ^ 2)
```

but it throw me this error:

```
 • Couldn't match type ‘(Float, Float) -> Bool’ with ‘Bool’
      Expected type: (Float, Float) -> Bool
        Actual type: (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float) -> Bool
    • Probable cause: ‘auxPuntos’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘auxPuntos’
      In the expression: filter auxPuntos z
      In an equation for ‘puntosEnCircunferencia’:
          puntosEnCircunferencia a y z
            = filter auxPuntos z
            where
                auxPuntos (w, s) (k, r) = ((k - w) ^ 2 + (r - s) ^ 2) < (a ^ 2)
```

What im doing wrong. Im starting with Haskell so I don't have much experience to fix this. 
Thanks.

Comment: You are calling `filter` with a function that takes two arguments, but `filter` expects a function that wants only one argument. Where are you planning for the second argument to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puntosCircunferencia` takes three arguments: a radius `a`, a center `y`, and a list of points `z`. `auxPuntos` should test if a *single* given point is with a distance `a` of point `y`, and as such should only take a single argument.

Below, I replace `y` with a pattern to match the components, as we need those in the definition of `auxPuntos`.

```
puntosEnCircunferencia a (x0, y0) zs = filter auxPuntos zs
   where auxPuntos (x1, y1) = ((x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2) < (a^2)
```

Another (possibly) clearer way to write this is to define a distance function as well.

```
puntosEnCircunferencia a y zs = filter auxPuntos zs
    where auxPuntos p = squareDistance p y < a^2
          squareDistance (x0, y0) (x1, y1) = (x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2
```

(In either case, you can drop `zs` as an explicit argument:

```
puntosEnCircunferencia a y = filter auxPuntos
  where ...
```

)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is in the **where** pattern matching, the ghci tell us:

```
Expected type: (Float, Float) -> Bool
        Actual type: (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float) -> Bool
```

Now lets get back into your code, you have:

```
where auxPuntos (w,s) (k,r) = ((k - w)^2 + (r - s)^2) < (a ^ 2)
```

Above you're calling auxPuntos with 2 parameters (two arrays), but you only have one list of arrays **z** not two.

```
filter auxPuntos z
```

But remember the type of filter is:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

So we only apply a filter to [a], to solve this we need to add the k and r values into the **where**:

```
puntosEnCircunferencia a b z= filter p z
    where
      k = b !! 0
      r = b !! 1
      p (w,s)= ((k - w)^2 + (r - s)^2) < a^2

ghci> largestDivisible 1 [2,1] [(1,2),(3,4)]
```